# Prolog Best Practice: checking if a variable is already bound.

Tags: prolog

I posted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984104/prolog-beginner-how-to-make-unique-values-for-each-variable-in-a-predicate/3000352#3000352) to an question but [ony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230744/ony) left me a comment saying:

> Predicates to check if "variable" is
>   free or already bound should change
>   strategy for deriving right
>   unifications for other "variables"
>   (i.e. speed up, or make possible to
>   derive them). The same for dynamic
>   predicates - they can be used to
>   speed-up something, but they shouldn't
>   be used as trigger of changing
>   behaviour of something.

I am wondering why this is.  Why is it bad practice to check if something is already defined to something else?  Do you think it is bad practice?  Are there other options that would be 'better practice'.

Here was my solution:

```
% ================================
% Ensures that all variables are unique.  
% ================================

% Base case: Assigned variables unique values
used([], Nin, Nin).

% Have already assigned a value to this variable
used([A|B], Nin, Nout) :-
        integer(A), % <----------------- THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION
        helper(B,Nin,Nout).

% Have not assigned a value to this variable yet
% Assign it and remove it from the list.  
used( [A|B] , Nin, Nout) :-
        member(A,Nin),
        delete(Nin,A,Temp),
        helper(B,Temp,Nout).
```

Comment: I did also left comment about meta-predicates. `nonvar/1` is one of them and is ok while you define such predicates without mix meaning of them with pure predicates (like `=/2` and `member/2`). But in original question there was `addUnique/2` which allowed to satify `addUnique([0,0,3],3)` (zero mentioned twice) when they passed directly but wasn't produced that result within results of `addUnique([A,B,C],3)`.

Comment: Please see how [safer tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27306453/772868) are possible. Another approach is to use [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/772868).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fundamental problem of predicates like `integer/1`, `atom/1` etc. is that they are **not monotonic**.

Take for example `?- integer(5).`, which succeeds. But a **more general** goal, `?- integer(X).`, **fails**!

For declarative debugging and automatically generated explanations, we expect that if a goal succeeds, every generalization of that goal must not fail.

The "proper" (i.e., if you want nice monotonic predicates that make declarative sense) thing to do would be for `integer/1` to raise an *instantiation error* on queries like `?- integer(X).` on the grounds that it does not have enough information to answer the question at this time. Instead of `integer/1`, you should use `must_be/2` from `library(error)` to obtain this sound behaviour:

```
?- must_be(integer, X).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

`must_be/2` behaves monotonically, which is in general a nice property.

Extending ony's comment: The problem is that (at least if the sample results above are correct) your predicate is no longer a true relation because goals are now not commutative: `?- X = 0, X = Y, addUnique([X,Y,3],3).` succeeds, but simply exchanging the order of goals does not yield the same result because `?- X = Y, addUnique([X,Y,3], 3), X = 0.` fails.

Such phenomena are common consequence of using meta-logical predicates. The declarative solution to such problems are **constraints**, see for example **`dif/2`**. They are monotonic, commutative and generally much easier to understand.