# Prolog wildcard for completing a string

Tags: prolog

I am currently stuck on a prolog problem.

So far I have:

`film(Title) :- movie(Title,_,_).`  (Where '`movie(T,_,_,)`' is a reference to my database)

```
namesearch(Title, Firstword) :- film(Title), contains_term(Firstword, Title).
```

It is hard to explain what I need help on, but basically is there a wildcard I can use to search for all  films starting with a specific word, for example, if I were to search for all films beginning with the word "The".

Is there a wildcard which would allow me to input as such: `namesearch(X,'The*')` ?

I have tried using the asterisk like this and it does not work,

Thank your for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends how the title is represented.

### Atom

If it is represented as an atom, you need `sub_atom(Atom, Before, Length, After, Sub_atom)`

```
?- Title = 'The Third Man', sub_atom(Title, 0, _, _, 'The').
   Title = 'The Third Man'.
```

### List of codes

If it is a list of codes which is called a string in Prologs in Edinburgh tradition, you can either "hard code" it with `append/3` or you might use Definite Clause Grammars for general patterns.

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,codes).
   true.
?- append("The",_, Pattern), Title = "The Third Man", Pattern = Title.
   Pattern = Title, Title = [84,104,101,32,84,104,105,114,100|...].
?- Title = "The Third Man", phrase(("The",...), Title).
   Title = [84,104,101,32,84,104,105,114,100|...]
;  false.
```

Note that 84 is the character code of T etc.

`phrase/2` is "the entry" to grammars. See [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for more. Above used the following definition:

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

### List of characters

Similar to list of codes, list of characters provide a more readable representation that has still the advantages of being compatible with list predicates and Definite Clause Grammars:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).
   true.
?- append("The",_, Pattern), Title = "The Third Man", Pattern = Title.
   Pattern = Title, Title = ['T',h,e,' ','T',h,i,r,d|...].

?- Title = "The Third Man", phrase(("The",...), Title).
   Title = ['T',h,e,' ','T',h,i,r,d|...]
;  false.
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868).

Comment: Eh... you beat me to suggesting `sub_atom/4` by 3 minutes (+1). :)

Comment: @lurker: Why don't you answer [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27306453/772868)? It is waiting here since a month, I wasted a total of 400 on bounties on it (that is, there was nobody to award 400 rep...).

Comment: for some reason, I didn't see that one. Apologies. I'll have a look at it.