# Using a univ operator in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to develop a prolog procedure that will convert numbers in any given list to a list of their square roots, using the univ (`=..`). So far I have

```
convert(X,Y): number(X), Y is X^2.
use([],_,[]).
use([_|X],convert,L):-
           convert(X,Y),
           L =..[convert,X,Y].
```

This evaluates false, what could be wrong in my logic or execution?

Comment: Typo: `convert(X,Y): number(X)...` --> `convert(X,Y) :- number(X)...`. Do you mean square roots or squares? Your code is doing squares. Why are you using `=../2`? It's purpose is to provide an equivalence between a term and a list. It's unclear how you think this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors:

- why passing the name of the predicate *convert/2*?
- Most important I see no recursive call!!
- You ignore head element of the list by writing [_|X] which means a list with a head element and a tail X.
- You try to use convert on X which is a **list** and assign the atom convert(X,Y) to L. Note that prolog is not a procedural language, convert(X,Y) will work only by just calling convert(X,Y) and the result will be in Y, you can't make assignments like: `L = convert(X,Y)` this will only assign the `atom convert(X,Y)` to L.

You don't need the operator `=..`, as a simple solution would be:

```
convert(X,Y):- number(X), Y is X^2.
use([],[]).
use([H|T],[Y|T1]):-
           convert(H,Y),
           use(T,T1).
```

Comment: You're code is missing a `-`  after the `:` in the first line. And the first goal of of use/2 should be `convert(H,Y)` ;-)

Comment: Thanks I will use use, I had no idea of that predicate.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `maplist/3` to define `use/2` with `convert/2` as defined in your post:

```
use(X,Y) :- maplist(convert, X, Y).

   ?- use([1,2,3],L).
L = [1,4,9]
```

Note that `use/2` is simply failing for lists that contain anything but numbers:

```
   ?- use([1,2,3,a],L).
no
```

Comment: That `convert/2`... succeeds for `convert(X, 2)` with `X = 2`, but fails for `X = 2, convert(X, 2)`.

Comment: @false: Thanks for pointing it out. That detail totally slipped my attention. I removed the faulty code.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306453/safer-type-tests-in-prolog) for a source of inspiration!