# Issue with Prolog code doing summation of elements in a list

Tags: prolog

Hoping you are well. I am fairly new to prolog and I am having an issue with a code that I am writing. The purpose of the code is quite simple. It adds each element from a list until the last one. Something I could do in Java as:

```java
    static void add(double[] array){
        double x = .0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
            x += array[i];
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

However, I have been scratching my head about how to do it in prolog.
I have the following code

```
add_list([], X):- write(X).
add_list([Head|Tail],X) :- 
    Y is Head,
    X is 0 + Y, %initialize X and add Y every time it runs.
    add_list(Tail, X).
```

The error I do get is that the variable X is already bounded when the code runs for the second time which makes sense, but I don't really know how to go about solving the issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `X` appears in three places in the second clause - you are using it the same as a variable in languages that change their state using assignment. Be aware that in this setting this means that Prolog will _make sure that_ or _ascertain that_ the same values appears in those three places. `X` is best though of as a reference to a shared memory location. Evidently `add_list([Head|Tail],X)` cannot have the same `X` as `add_list(Tail,X)` on its second argument location.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prolog programs are relations.  Using a name starting with `add_` sounds more like an imperative program.  If you want to learn Prolog, avoid such names as much as you can.  In this case you want to establish a relation between a list and the sum of its elements. `list_sum/2` sounds like a much better name.

```
:- use_module(library(clpz)). % or clpfd
:- op(150, fx, #).

list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([E|Es], S) :-
   #S #= #E + #Si,
   list_sum(Es, Si).
```

Now, given that definition, try it out!

```
?- list_sum([1,2,3], N).
   N = 6.
?- list_sum([1,2,3], 7).
   false.
?- list_sum([1,2,E], 7).
   E = 4.
?- list_sum([1,E,E], 7).
   E = 3.
```

Comment: This uses [constraint programming](https://github.com/triska/clpz) and the `#=` operator instead of _"function evaluation on the right-hand-side, and [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) with the left-hand-side as in `LHS is RHS`_, but why declare a `#` infix operator to prefix `S` to `#S` for example?

Comment: Otherwise `N = 1+0, list_sum([1], N).` succeeds whereas `list_sum([1], N), N = 1+0.` fails. Thus, non-relational.

Comment: I see. But for the first goal, one might have reason to see it succeed, whereas `list_sum([1], N), N = 1+0.` will never succeed because the programmer messed up bad, trying to unify an integer and a term. In fact, a compiler might succeed in telling the programmer that `list_sum([1], N), N = 1+0.` will always yield false, no matter what. So is it reasonable to preclude success for `N = 1+0, list_sum([1], N).`?

Comment: It is virtually impossible to catch **all** such cases by a compiler. Also, what about `N = 0+0` which never works for `[]`

Comment: Of course, it is provably impossible to catch everything. But one does not need perfection, for example the Idris compiler will tell you when it suspects your loop isn't going to terminate, which can be useful. Anyway, `N = 0+0` will indeed not work, unless you have first reduction of `0+0`. I guess that's for another language (unification with equality, innit?)

Comment: `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- op(150, fx, #).` are those library that you are using? I am not familiar with those.

Comment: Also do you have any documentation on prolog you can recommend? Those that I have seen so far are quite hard to understand.

Comment: I have both Linux & Windows.

Comment: gprolog would be it I suppose.

Comment: On GNU-Prolog  remove the 3 prefix #. Otherwise it should work

Comment: @false I wish. But I have served far too long in "industry" in the desert of Java the Hutt and his merry frameworks and reinvented square wheels. Declarative Languages have an actual theory that goes beyond "changing state arbitrarily at every step", this piques my interest.

Comment: @David: OTOH, being over-ambitious can easily lead to overlook the small and still critical issues. Think of the [type testing deaster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27306453/772868), which was caused by the omission of errors and their incorrect replacement by silent failure in DEC10.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a way to get the result I need. Following the advice of @false I renamed my rule from ***add_list*** to ***list_sum***. I came up with the following code that works, but will need a digit (0 ideally. Any other number will increase the result by that number.) to be provided when it is called.

```
list_sum([], X):- write(X). 
list_sum([Head|Tail], X)  :- 
    K is X,
    W is K + Head, 
    list_sum(Tail, W).
```

The issue with the code now is that if you enter 1 instead of 0 as the initial variable as mentioned above, it increases the result by 1. I am not totally satisfied with the result to be honest.

Comment: Tip: don't mix *computation* with *output*. If you want to print a successful goal bindings, you can always call e.g. `g(X), write(X)`.